# Visual Studio: Suppress warnings for all files in a namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

I have following namespaces in my project.

[image]

I want to disable a specific warning on a specific namespace (lets say Project.ViewModels). I can disable a warning on one files by doing this in the `GlobalSuppression.cs`

```
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Formatting", "RCS1057:Add empty line between declarations.", Justification = "<Pending>", Scope = "type", Target = "~T:Project.ViewModels.MainViewModel.cs")]
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Formatting", "RCS1057:Add empty line between declarations.", Justification = "<Pending>", Scope = "type", Target = "~T:Project.ViewModels.TreeViewModel.cs")]
```

I tried to change `Scope` from `type` to `namespace` and `namespaceanddescendants` but it didn't work.

```
[assembly: SuppressMessage("Formatting", "RCS1057:Add empty line between declarations.", Justification = "<Pending>", Scope = "namespace", Target = "~T:Project.ViewModels")]
```

Any idea how this can be fixed? I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: ``~T:Project.ViewModels`` doesn't seem a valid namespace

Comment: @ganchito55 I tried without `~T` as well, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria this will suppress warning for whole project, I only want to suppress for one namespace.

Comment: The suppressmessage attribute didn't work for me in this case. For those of you who want to go the MSBUILD way, here's the link: http://lvquoc.blogspot.com/2010/11/disable-xml-comment-warning-in-workflow.html Looks like a hardcore-approach but looks promising.

Answer (score 11):

You shouldn't use the `~T:` for a namespace, that seems to only be for types.  For a usage example, you can see how it's not being used for the namespace in [the .NET Core code here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Collections.Immutable/GlobalSuppressions.cs,5).  Also, [from the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/in-source-suppression-overview?view=vs-2019#suppressmessage-attribute) `namespace` only:

> suppresses warnings against the namespace itself. It does not suppress warnings against types within the namespace as shown below:

Depending on your file hierarchy, you'll potentially want to use `namespaceanddescendants` as shown below:

```
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Formatting", "RCS1057:Add empty line between declarations.", Justification = "<Pending>", Scope = "namespaceanddescendants", Target = "Project.ViewModels")]
```

Comment: The `Target` value's format is legacy. It should be `~N:Project.ViewModels`.